# Error with double precision data type InvalidTextRepresentation Syntax error psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a table with psycopg2 but I cannot figure out what is causing the problem exactly. From what I can tell, the problem appears to be the columns that have positive and negative decimal values. I know there are several questions about syntax error but I could not find one that help me.

Here is my code:

```
# Settings
hostname = 'localhost'
database = 'postgres'
username = 'postgres'
pwd = 'my password here'
port_id = 5432

# Establishing connection with database

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host = hostname,
    dbname = database,
    user = username,
    password = pwd,
    port = port_id)

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pfa_wls")
conn.commit()

cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE pfa_wls (
    crim_id VARCHAR(200),
    month VARCHAR(10),
    reported_by VARCHAR(50),
    falls_within VARCHAR(50),
    longitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
    latitude DOUBLE PRECISION,
    location VARCHAR(100),
    LSOA_code VARCHAR(20),
    LSOA_name VARCHAR(100),
    crim_type VARCHAR(100),
    last_outcome_category VARCHAR(100),
    context VARCHAR(20) ) 
    ''')
    
conn.commit()

# Loading files into postgres database
with open('combined_pfa_wls.csv') as csvFile:
   next(csvFile) # Skipping headers
   cur.copy_from(csvFile, "pfa_wls", sep=",")
   
   # Commit the transaction
   conn.commit()
```

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Vanessa\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7728\2693380821.py", line 33, in <module>
    cur.copy_from(csvFile, "pfa_wls", sep=",")

InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
CONTEXT:  COPY pfa_wls, line 3788, column longitude: ""
```

Here is an example of the data contained in the column in question:

[image]

I changed `DOUBLE PRECISION` to `FLOAT` but no luck. Help and suggestions much appreciated.

Comment: The issue is there are empty strings in that column and that won't work: `select ''::float;
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""`.

Answer (score 0):

> InvalidTextRepresentation: invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
> CONTEXT:  COPY pfa_wls, line 3788, column longitude: ""

Well, it's pretty simple.

Quoting rules for CSV format are not well standardized.
The software which wrote that CSV, and the
postgres software that's reading it,
do not agree on the rules.

In particular, quotes or special or white space
characters are causing reader to get out of sync
with writer at about line 3788.
It appears you'd be able to successfully INSERT
the initial thirty-seven-hundred rows
from a truncated file.

Delete the initial 3786 or so rows, preserving headers.
Then manually inspect for "odd" characters.
You might use a spreadsheet app to view the data.
Once you understand the details,
either fix the code or fix the data,
then repeat the ETL.

Comment: No need to do all this. The error message is saying what the 'odd' character is, it is an empty string. That is not valid for a `float/double precision`: `select ''::float; ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""`.

Comment: Sure, I understand, could be. My assumption was that it was valid data to the writer and then after CSV channel corruption a non-longitude field was presented to the reader as though it was a longitude field. What we both can agree on is that OP neglected to show us the relevant data line or two, a few thousand rows into the file.